# Using SqlConnection in tasks - 'ByRef' parameter 'cnn' cannot be used in a lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, lambda

I need to run some tasks where I pass an SqlConnection (due to transaction state).

Here's my code:

```
Public Class CustomerModel
    Public Property Name As String
End Class


Public Shared Function GetData(ByRef cnn As SqlConnection, zipCodes As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim tasks As Task(Of CustomerModel)() = New Task(Of CustomerModel)(zipCodes.Count - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each zipCode As String In zipCodes
        tasks(i) = Task.Run(Of CustomerModel)(Function() (GetCustomer(cnn)))
        i += 1
    Next
    Task.WaitAll(tasks)
End Function


Private Shared Function GetCustomer(ByRef cnn As SqlConnection) As CustomerModel
End Function
```

But I get this error:

> 'ByRef' parameter 'cnn' cannot be used in a lambda expression.

Is this impossible to do - or how can I fix it?

Thx

Comment: Why are you passing it ByRef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't use `ByRef`. You are not writing to the parameter `cnn` anyway so there's no point in using `ByRef`. Maybe you don't know that reference types are always passed ... by reference in .NET.

Comment: Are reference type really passed by reference by default?  I always thought that if you don't specify `ByRef` then arguments are passed `ByVal`, even for reference types.  For reference types, the value passed is a copy of the reference, but it is still passed by value.  If you change the reference in the called code, it will not affect the reference in the calling code as it would if `ByRef` were used.

Comment: Yes, the reference is passed by value which is what you want 99.9% of the time. I think the OP did not understand this.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression declared within a Sub or function cannot use any ByRef parameters of that Sub or function. For example, the following code will cause this error because the ByRef parameter n is used in the lambda expression.

to correct the error,Assign the ByRef parameter to a local variable, and use the local variable in the lambda expression, as shown in the following code:

```
Public Shared Function GetData(ByRef cnn As SqlConnection, zipCodes As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim tasks As Task(Of CustomerModel)() = New Task(Of CustomerModel)(zipCodes.Count - 1) {}
    Dim conn as SqlConnection = cnn
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each zipCode As String In zipCodes
        tasks(i) = Task.Run(Of CustomerModel)(Function() (GetCustomer(conn)))
        i += 1
    Next
    Task.WaitAll(tasks)
End Function
```

**Reference**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531324(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Class CustomerModel
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Public Shared Function GetData(cnn As SqlConnection, zipCodes As List(Of String)) As String
    Task.WaitAll(zipCodes.Select(Function(z) Task.Run(Function() GetCustomer(cnn))).ToArray)
End Function

Private Shared Function GetCustomer(cnn As SqlConnection) As CustomerModel
    '
End Function
```